# How to check kubectl execution history of a kubernetes cluster?

Tags: security, kubernetes

Suppose I have a Kubernetes cluster, devops manages the cluster using kubectl. How can I track the kubectl execution on the cluster to monitor if there is any suspicious activities?

Comment: Audit logs is one way

Comment: Apparomor and Falco are other tech that may help if correctly implemented